# ModX Output a chunk if screen width is certain size

Tags: javascript, modx, modx-revolution

So I'm trying to output a lengthy chunk of HTML code if the browser width is 590px or less (mobile view). I have a simple javascript function that determines the screen's width on resize, but how do I output a chunk if that function returns true?

The way I'm envisioning it is to have the function inside it's own chunk, but I can't get the chunk to return anything to any output filters, e.g.
        `[[$isMobile:eq=`true`:then=`[[$MobileChunk]]`]]`

Thanks

Comment: 18 hours late, but it's never too late to help. If I were you I'd output the contents of the chunk in a div with display:none; then in your JS just set it to block when the viewport matches your specific dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a simple javascript function that determines the screen's width on resize, but how do I output a chunk if that function returns true?

JS can't modify MODX output. Also MODX can't rely on JS. It's all because you have JS at frontend and PHP at backend.

Anyway you can solve your problem different ways.

1. First of all you can check user's user-agent and modify output according to a result.
2. Another method was already mentioned at comments. You can render you block at html-element with `display:none` and make it `block` when width is 590 or less. But this is not good for SEO cause search engine can get this content.
3. Also you can make an AJAX request to your server and render your chunk at success.

Answer (score 0):

I think you do this with http://modx.com/extras/package/mobiletemplateswitcher

Never used it. I think you can use different "templates" in the template.

```
<mobile>
  {{mymobilechunk}}
</mobile>
<template>
  {{mynormalchunk}}
</template>
```

Its not the nicest way but you can use CSS.
Other than that I don't think its possible..

```
@media all and (max-width: 590px) {
    .mobile-show{display:block;}
    .mobile-hide{display:none;}
}
```